# Rewrite rule to handle IP address urls

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to direct all traffic that comes in via an explicit IP address to one particular domain. I have applied the following rewrite rule, but it's losing any path/query variables:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://default-domain.com/$1 [L]
```

For example:
http://259.16.44.10/custom/path/ should be directed to http://default-domain.com/custom/path/, but instead it's being rewritten as http://default-domain.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered later that the url redirect was in actual fact being processed by WordPress. It was converting the IP-based url to a domain-based one and then doing a 301. The problem was that in the process it was not preserving any path or query components of the url. I simply edited the WordPress code to pass on these with the redirect.

Editing core WordPress code is not advisable, but since this site is running off my dev machine, then it's no issue.